# Call method on derived form from the base form

Tags: c#, inheritance, visual-inheritance

I've been trying to play with Visual Inheritance so that I can reuse a set of buttons in multiple forms.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is, I want the buttons to have same visual behavior across the different forms, however, they should perform different actions depending on which form is  inheriting it.

Suppose I have the following buttons in `FormButtonBar`

> New | Edit | Search | Cancel | Close

They should be disabled or have their text and icons changed according to the current situation going on (I do that using `.Tag`), these are the alternative options displayed

> Save | Save | Remove | Cancel | Close

Even though I got that working as supposed on forms that inherit this, I obviously want these buttons to deal with different content depending on which form I have them.

What I thought of was a way to call methods like `saveNewItem()` `saveChangedItem()` `removeItem()` that every form inheriting `FormButtonBar` should have.

But how do I call them from `FormButtonBar`?

For example:

```
    private void buttonSearchRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (buttonSearchRemove.Tag == "search")
        {

            //call the search form here and wait for something to be returned

            //the following 3 lines are the ones that switch text, icons and enabled/disabled on the buttons

            utils.hablitarBotoes(panelBotoes, "abc");
            utils.alternarBotoes(panelBotoes, "b");
            buttonBuscarExcluir.Text = "Excluir";

        }
        else if (buttonSearchRemove.Tag == "remove")
        {
            DialogResult reply = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to remove it?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (reply == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                  //CALL REMOVE METHOD THAT SHOULD BE IN THE FORM INHERITING THIS ONE, BUT HOW?

                  removeItem();

              }

                utils.hablitarBotoes(panelBotoes, "nbf");
                utils.alternarBotoes(panelBotoes, "");

                buttonNovoSalvar.Text = "New";
                buttonBuscarExcluir.Text = "Search";
                buttonAlterarSalvar.Text = "Edit";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should declare all the methods (you mentioned) in the base class and override those methods in the derived classes.

Comment: But if I do that, wont I lose the code ive implemented in the base class for switching the text and icons and end up having to reimplement them in the derived form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare these methods in base class as virtual methods and then override them in child classes.

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual void RemoveItems()
    {
    }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass 
{
    public override void RemoveItems()
    {
       //your specific implementation for this child class
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose thats gonna work! Im away from home now, Ill test that as soon as I can.  Thank you EVER SO MUCH!